# Ruby Watir: when_present not appropriately waiting until things are present?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm having an issue getting when_present to actually wait until the element is present in certain cases.  The problem occurs only intermittently, but it always happens when changing pages.

Example: I want to click save on the current page, then enter text into a field on the subsequent page.

If I do:

```
 $browser.button(:value => "Save").click
 sleep 3
 $browser.text_field(:label => "Name").when_present.set "Leelluu"
```

tt works fine.

However, if I do:

```
 $browser.button(:value => "Save").click
 $browser.text_field(:label => "Name").when_present.set "Leelluu"
```

it times out/crashes immediately after clicking "Save".

How do I fix this?

(I know, it seems like I *have* fixed it by using sleep, but my boss has told me that the sleeps are wasting time.  He says I need to remove all of them from the code and find another way.)

Updating with a real-world example..... I enter a search text, then click the search button, then want to select the checkbox next to the leading checkbox on the returned list.

```
 $browser.text_field(:id => /.*search*./).set "Snow Leopard"
 $browser.button(:id => "save_filter_PricebookEntry").when_present.click
 $browser.checkbox(:id => "allBox").when_present.set
```

I get an "element not clickable" (even though it has a when_present) on it.

```
 unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (251, 482). Other element would receive the click:
 ...
 (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.57) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

 ["D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:369:in `clickElement'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/checkbox.rb:26:in `set'", "D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:100:in `method_missing'", "D:/Desktop/jardine/utils.rb:143:in `addQLIs'", "D:/Desktop/jardine/noSleepTest.rb:31:in `block in '", "D:/Desktop/jardine/framework.rb:39:in `execute'", "D:/Desktop/jardine/framework.rb:61:in `block in runTestCases'", "D:/Desktop/jardine/framework.rb:60:in `each'", "D:/Desktop/jardine/framework.rb:60:in `runTestCases'", "jardine.rb:66:in `
 '"]
```

Comment: What is the exception that you get (when not using sleep)?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what's going on.  An intermediate url is popping up for about 100 ms before it gets to the destination url.  Watir is apparently checking that intermediary url for my field, not finding it by the time the browser moves to the actual expected page, and then crashing.  How can I get around this without a sleep?

Comment: I do not believe it should matter if an intermediate page is displayed. Can you please add the full stacktrace just in case?

Comment: I added a real-world example and stack trace above.  It's not the precise case I was first describing, but it's another place my boss insists I get rid of the sleep.

Comment: The stacktrace is quite different than "Element not on page". The element is on the page, but it is being overlayed by some other element. Is there something that covers the checkbox (temporarily)?

Comment: Sorry.  Like I said, it's an intermittent problem, and I couldn't get it to pop today on the case I first described.  This is another place I need to find a way to sleep without "sleep" that *is* popping today.  There is a "searching" visual element that is in the section below the section containing the checkbox, but not in front of it.